# Selenium version for IE11 application running with JDK 1.6

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11

I have a web application which is running with `JDK 1.6` and I am using Internet Explorer 11 (`IE11`) version to test the same. Currently I am using Selenium version 2.45.0.

What is the latest Selenium version I can use for my application running with `JDK 1.6`?. I think there is a limitation with the Selenium version and JDK.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the version 2.45.0 should work, only thing is to keep in mind when working in IE 11 is these three things :
(a) All security zones are set to the same Protected Mode setting. 
(b) Enhanced Protected Mode is turned off. 
(c) Zoom level is set to 100%.